# Как убрать лишние кнопки сворачивания в Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В очередной раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, в visual studio появляется такая сворачивающая кнопочка, которая обычно привязана к методам классам и тд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать через:

```
Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced
```

либо любой другой язык:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
либо сочетание клавиш:

```
CTRL + M + L
```

вот есть [хороший пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/982704/9363441) как решить проблему